# Four Parenthesis?

Tags: parenthesis

> This fish swam (around, and around) (maybe, around, some seaweed).

If you may have two, maybe, parenthetical thoughts, each, maybe, somewhat different, may it seem grammatical, and proper, to use, maybe, four, maybe, parenthesis?

Comment: You'd do better to enclose the whole in one pair of brackets, and disjoin the separate comments with a dash: *(around and around&mdash;maybe around some seaweed)*. And I implore you to eschew the comma except when it serves some essential purpose.

Comment: That may seem maybe interesting. So, it may seem proper, and grammatical, to use two parenthesis, and, I guess, one, maybe, (em[?]) dash?